# Compare list elements with string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of db table type I want to access list elements and compare with string but I cannot access list elements How to do it?

```
List<Tbl_UserCustomField> customattribute = (from custom in tniDataContext.Tbl_UserCustomFields 
                                             where workOrderIndex.LoginId == custom.LoginId 
                                             select custom).ToList();
```

After executing the query and storing the query result in list the customattribute is only returning count of elements in list but i want elements in string

Comment: I might not understand you correctly, but in order to get the contents of the list, you need to iterate it.

Comment: you need to descibe what is `Tbl_UserCustomFields`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov but how to get this list elements in string?

Comment: We need to know what you store in your `Tbl_UserCustomField` type.

Comment: @tafia tbl_usercustomfields is a db table

Comment: Can you give an example of what is your input, what you expect and what you actually get?

Comment: @hisham shahid - what `string` are you looking for?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov tbl_usercustomfields has four columns three of int type one of nvarchar

Comment: Its strange when you say it returns count... share model details for Tbl_UserCustomField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access it like:

```
foreach(var item in customattribute)
{
    if(item.SomeField == "someString")
       DoSomething();
    else
       DoSomethingElse();
}
```

If the varchar column is all you want then you can directly select it:

```
var customattribute = (from custom in tniDataContext.Tbl_UserCustomFields 
                       where workOrderIndex.LoginId == custom.LoginId 
                       select custom.SomeColumn).ToList();

foreach(var item in customattribute)
{
    if(item == "someString")
       DoSomething();
    else
       DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: @hisham shahid - Is it your string ?

Comment: I didnt get the question, sorry.

Comment: `ToList()` is redundant (and can be even harmful) here

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri - Nothing to you. I just wanted to know if hisham found his answar.?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, of course deferred execution will make it, but I have just copy pasted.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Yes I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try `customattribute.ForEach(i => Console.Write("{0}\t", i));` and see what is showing on console?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the column or property in Tbl_UserCustomField class which holds the string you are looking for, iterate through the customattribute and fetch the string. Basically, you will have to capture such result in a variable of type  `List<string>`. This can be done in a plain foreach-way OR using a Select Linq expression that just retrieves the column you specify

```
        // Approach 1:
        List<string> customAttributeValues = customattribute.Select(c => c.YourStringFieldName).ToList();

        // Approach 2:
        List<string> customAttributeValues = new List<string>();
        foreach (var custom in customattribute)
        {
            customAttributeValues.Add(custom.YourStringFieldName);
        }
```